# Why instance_size is 0 for fundamental GType types?

Tags: c, types, glib, type-systems

There are a bunch of fundamental types being registered in GLib's GType subsystem (GLib's source file `gvaluetypes.c` follows):

```
/* --- type initialization --- */
void
_g_value_types_init (void)
{
  GTypeInfo info = {
    0,              /* class_size */
    NULL,           /* base_init */
    NULL,           /* base_destroy */
    NULL,           /* class_init */
    NULL,           /* class_destroy */
    NULL,           /* class_data */
    0,              /* instance_size */
    0,              /* n_preallocs */
    NULL,           /* instance_init */
    NULL,           /* value_table */
  };
  const GTypeFundamentalInfo finfo = { G_TYPE_FLAG_DERIVABLE, };
  GType type G_GNUC_UNUSED  /* when compiling with G_DISABLE_ASSERT */;
  
  /* G_TYPE_CHAR / G_TYPE_UCHAR
   */
  {
    static const GTypeValueTable value_table = {
      value_init_long0,     /* value_init */
      NULL,         /* value_free */
      value_copy_long0,     /* value_copy */
      NULL,         /* value_peek_pointer */
      "i",          /* collect_format */
      value_collect_int,    /* collect_value */
      "p",          /* lcopy_format */
      value_lcopy_char,     /* lcopy_value */
    };
    info.value_table = &value_table;
    type = g_type_register_fundamental (G_TYPE_CHAR, g_intern_static_string ("gchar"), &info, &finfo, 0);
    g_assert (type == G_TYPE_CHAR);
    type = g_type_register_fundamental (G_TYPE_UCHAR, g_intern_static_string ("guchar"), &info, &finfo, 0);
    g_assert (type == G_TYPE_UCHAR);
  }
  …
  …
  …
```

I wonder why `instance_size` of `info` struct isn't being used? Don't fundamental types have/use any "instance size"? I'm planning on using this subsystem to register a few types,
including fundamental ones, and I wonder if I should specify,
e.g.: `8` for `instance_size` for a `gint64`–equivalent type?

In general, what's wrong with specifying a true, real size of a basic type? It shouldn't do any harm? If yes, then why GLib's doesn't use this feature ?

Comment: IDK but all the members have been initialised to `0` or `NULL`. Advantages are that a structure that isn't filled will fail predictably, and the lack of initialisation can also be detected.

Comment: ...but isn't it the size of the object, not a pointer?

Comment: Answer here: https://discourse.gnome.org/t/why-instance-size-is-0-for-fundamental-gtype-types/6588/2